# how to iterate through one column in matrix?

Tags: image, matlab, matrix, hsv

I read an image in using `I = imread('myimg.jpg')`, then did `hsv = rgb2hsv(I)` but now I'm stuck in doing the following:

"Go through each element of `HSV(i,j,3)` [`i` and `j` are like for loop counters] and scale the value from 0-1 to 1-256 and use that value as the index into your histogram."

I'm new to matlab so I'm very unsure as to how to do this. Can anyone help me out?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use the [colon operator](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html):

```
I = imread('myimg.jpg');
hsv = rgb2hsv(I);
scale_factor = 255
result = hsv(:, :, 3) * scale_factor + 1
```

Comment: And if you're using that as a index to your histogram, use `round(result)`